# Deck class in Blackjack in Python

Tags: python, oop, blackjack

I am currently working on a Deck (for playing cards) class in for a text-based blackjack game and I'm having some difficulty in printing out the cards using the deck class even though my nested dictionary works (I've tested it).

The code is below:

```
import random

cards  = {'Hearts': {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':10,
         'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':11}, 
          'Diamonds': {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':10,
         'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':11},
          'Spades': {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':10,
         'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':11},
          'Clubs': {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':10,
         'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':11}}

playing = True

class Deck:

    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        for outer_key in cards:
            'Outer Key = ',outer_key
            for inner_key in cards[outer_key]:
                self.deck.append(('{} of {}'.format(inner_key,outer_key))

    def __str__(self):
        x = ''
        for card in self.deck:
            x += '\n' + card.__init__()
        return 'The deck has: ' + x 

test_deck = Deck()
print(test_deck)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code had a couple of problems - mismatched parenthesis, and you don't need to call `card.__init__()`.

I fixed it up and this works for me:

```py
import random

cards = {'Hearts':
         {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':10, 'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':11}, 
         'Diamonds':
         {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':10, 'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':11},
         'Spades':
         {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':10, 'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':11},
         'Clubs':
         {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':10, 'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':11}}

playing = True

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        for outer_key in cards:
            'Outer Key = ',outer_key
            for inner_key in cards[outer_key]:
                self.deck.append(('{} of {}'.format(inner_key,outer_key)))

    def __str__(self):
        x = ''
        for card in self.deck:
            x += '\n' + card
        return 'The deck has: ' + x 

test_deck = Deck()
print(test_deck)
```

Answer (score 0):

`card.__init__()` is a `NoneType` and you can't concatenate a `str` with it.

`__init__()` is called for you when you instantiate the class, no need to call it unless you're using inheritance to extend `__init__()` of child classes.